# Grouping columns if their values are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm new to Python and had a question, would appreciate if someone could please help:

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Chem1 | ChemValue1 | Chem2 | ChemValue2 | Chem3 | ChemValue3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carbon Monoxide | 32 | Carbon Dioxide | 32 | Carbon | 45 |
| Sulfur | 32 | Sulfur | 32 | Sulfur | 45 |
| Carbon | 32 | Carbon | 32 | Iron | 45 |
| Carbon | 32 | Iron | 32 | Iron | 45 |

If Chem1 equals Chem2 and/or Chem 3, I want to add up the corresponding ChemValue. So I get a dataset like this:

| Chem1 | ChemValue1 | Chem2 | ChemValue2 | Chem3 | ChemValue3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carbon Monoxide | 32 | Carbon Dioxide | 32 | Carbon | 45 |
| Sulfur | 109 | - | - | - | - |
| Carbon | 64 | - | - | Iron | 45 |
| Carbon | 32 | Iron | 77 | - | - |

Then I want to just get the Chem with the highest corresponding ChemValue (it's fine if I don't get the above table as an intemediary, just fine with getting the max aggregate Chem):

| Highest Chem |
| --- |
| Carbon Monoxide |
| Sulfur |
| Carbon |
| Iron |

How can I do this in Python?

```
#here is the first dataset

data = {'Chem1': ['Carbon Monoxide','Sulfur','Carbon','Carbon'], 'ChemValue1': [32,32,32,32],'Chem2': ['Carbon Dioxide','Sulfur','Carbon','Iron'],'ChemValue2': [32,32,32,32],'Chem3': ['Carbon','Sulfur','Iron','Iron'],'ChemValue3': [45,45,45,45]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: isn't sulfur the highest at 109, your table has carbon monoxide at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This do need more work than we think , the 2nd df can be done while we get the 1stdf

```
s = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),stubnames=['Chem','ChemValue'],i = 'index',j='v').reset_index()
#use pd.wide_to_long melt the df from row to column
secdf = s.groupby(['index','Chem'])['ChemValue'].sum().reset_index(level=0).groupby('index')['ChemValue'].idxmax()
# then we can do groupby combine the same value and get the max id of index 
Out[274]:
index
0    Carbon
1    Sulfur
2    Carbon
3      Iron
Name: ChemValue, dtype: object
s = s.groupby(['index','Chem']).agg({'ChemValue':'sum','v':'first'}).reset_index(level=1).set_index('v',append=True).unstack().sort_index(axis=1,level=1)
s.columns = s.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)
s
Out[288]: 
                 Chem1  ChemValue1  ...   Chem3  ChemValue3
index                               ...                    
0      Carbon Monoxide        32.0  ...  Carbon        45.0
1               Sulfur       109.0  ...     NaN         NaN
2               Carbon        64.0  ...    Iron        45.0
3               Carbon        32.0  ...     NaN         NaN
[4 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Gets both the datasets I'm after and scales well for a large number of rows/columns as well!

Answer (score 1):

This should get the final result that the question asks for:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'Chem1': ['Carbon Monoxide','Sulfur','Carbon','Carbon'], 'ChemValue1': [32,32,32,32],'Chem2': ['Carbon Dioxide','Sulfur','Carbon','Iron'],'ChemValue2': [32,32,32,32],'Chem3': ['Carbon','Sulfur','Iron','Iron'],'ChemValue3': [45,45,45,45]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

from collections import defaultdict
highestChem, highestChemValue = [], []
def aggregateChems(x):
    dct = defaultdict(int)
    for k, v in (('Chem1', 'ChemValue1'), ('Chem2', 'ChemValue2'), ('Chem3', 'ChemValue3')):
        dct[x[k]] += x[v]
    highestChem.append(max(dct, key=lambda x: dct[x]))
    highestChemValue.append(dct[highestChem[-1]])
df.apply(aggregateChems, axis = 1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'HighestChem' : highestChem, 'ChemValue' : highestChemValue})
print(f"\n{df2}")

df3 = df2['HighestChem'].to_frame()
print(f"\n{df3}")
```

Output:

```
             Chem1  ChemValue1           Chem2  ChemValue2   Chem3  ChemValue3
0  Carbon Monoxide          32  Carbon Dioxide          32  Carbon          45
1           Sulfur          32          Sulfur          32  Sulfur          45
2           Carbon          32          Carbon          32    Iron          45
3           Carbon          32            Iron          32    Iron          45

  HighestChem  ChemValue
0      Carbon         45
1      Sulfur        109
2      Carbon         64
3        Iron         77

  HighestChem
0      Carbon
1      Sulfur
2      Carbon
3        Iron
```

Comment: Thanks! Wish I could select more than one correct answer, this is very elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

I took a more manual approach that works fine for 3 Chem but won't scale well

```
c12 = df['Chem1'].eq(df['Chem2'])
c13 = df['Chem1'].eq(df['Chem3'])
df.loc[c12, 'ChemValue1'] = df['ChemValue1'] + df['ChemValue2']
df.loc[c13, 'ChemValue1'] = df['ChemValue1'] + df['ChemValue3']

c23 = df['Chem2'].eq(df['Chem3'])
df.loc[c23, 'ChemValue2'] = df['ChemValue2'] + df['ChemValue3']
pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),stubnames=['Chem','ChemValue'],i = 'index',j='k').reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
               Chem  ChemValue
0   Carbon Monoxide         32
1            Sulfur        109
2            Carbon         64
3            Carbon         32
4    Carbon Dioxide         32
5            Sulfur         77
6            Carbon         32
7              Iron         77
8            Carbon         45
9            Sulfur         45
10             Iron         45
11             Iron         45
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yeah in my actual dataset, I have more columns (10+)